# AjaxControlToolkit:CalendarExtender not working - Please advise

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I am extremely new to ASP.Net and I'm developing tools for my company operation through learning as I go and lots of trial and error.

I have researched the use of the AjaxControlToolkit:CalendarExtender for over a week now, my code matches each example of use, but it still will not work.

The below is entered at the top of my Site.Master page and Default.aspx;

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
```

Below is my ScriptManager;

```
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
        </Scripts>
    </ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Web Config;

```
<controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"           tagPrefix="ajax"/>
</controls>
```

CalendarExtender;

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>  
  <ajax:CalendarExtender   
    CssClass="cal_Theme1"   
    ID="CalendarExtender1"   
    runat="server"   
    PopupPosition="Right"  
    TargetControlID="TextBox1">  
</ajax:CalendarExtender>
```

My website currently loads, but the calendar does not show when clicking on `TextBox1`.

Any positive advise would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: The markup seems ok. Anything going on with Calendar in code behind?

Comment: I've not even started with the code behind yet, to be honest. All I have so far is the below;

Comment: `Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table
Imports System.Web.UI.Page
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data.OleDb
'Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
Imports System.Array
Imports System.Web`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help you but I've managed to get the Calender extender control to work quite easily in a new project by installing the Ajax Control Toolkit from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/). This will perform all the necessary modifications to your project for the toolkit to run and allow you to choose the new controls from the toolbox (Under General in my Toolbox).

Also quite handy is after you drag a textbox onto the form in designer mode you have the option to associate an extender with the control.

My markup is then simply:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
            TargetControlID="TextBox1">
        </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise. Running the Install code on the Package Manager Console (NuGet) solved the issue.